# How to find specific Elements in Lists which are part of Lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, extract

My problem is::

I have a List of instances of a class "company"
each company contains a list of a class "Car" and an unique id
each car has a lot of specific data like "brand" an "model"

My task is to create a new list which contains all duplicate cars with the companys id who use them. In each "car" class is an object `licensplateNO` which is also unique. So to check only for duplicate instances of Cars is no option because each instance is different in the licenseplate property. My last Idea would be to do it the old fashioned way with a lot of loops comparing each property of each element with each other.

the result should look like this:

```
list duplicateCars: 
Car1: BMW M4     used by Company B, Company F, Company X
Car2: Audi A3    used by Company B, Company D
Car3: VW  Golf   used by Company D, Company F .....
```

Comment: Iequalitycomparer is what ur looking for.

Comment: Create a `List<company>` with a sample data (A compilable code), write the output you expected and also attach the code you have tried so far. Now it can be a good question.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are looking for cars whose Make and Model appear in more than one company list?  And you'd like to know the car's make and model and the companies that include that car?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want can be achieved with the following.

```
var result = companies.SelectMany(
        company => company.Cars.Select(car => new {Car = car, Company = company}))
    .GroupBy(cc => new { cc.Car.Make, cc.Car.Model })
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grp => new 
        { 
            grp.Key.Make, 
            grp.Key.Model, 
            Companies = string.Join(", ", grp.Select(cc => cc.Company.CompanyName))
        });
```

First this selects all the companies and their cars, then it groups by the car's make and model, then it filters out the groups with only one type of car, and finally it selects the make and model of each unique type of car and creates a comma separated `string` of the company names.  You may need to change the code to work with the specific names of your class properties, or to change exactly what properties of the car you want to group on.

Or alternatively you can use query syntax

```
var result = from company in compaines
             from car in company.Cars
             group new { Company = company, Car = car }  by new { car.Make, car.Model } 
             into grp
             where grp.Count() > 1
             select new
             {
                 grp.Key.Make, 
                 grp.Key.Model, 
                 Companies = string.Join(", ", grp.Select(cc => cc.Company.CompanyName))
             };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Problem is now solved

Answer (score 1):

I suggest breaking up your task into steps:

1. Pair a car type (make and model) with a company and compile a master list of these.
2. Group these pairs by the Car instead of the company
3. Select only the groups with multiple companies (you might need to check distinct companies if you have duplicate entries in your original data)
4. You now have a Collection of `Car-List<Company>` groupings.  Print it or whatever

   ```
   var carDealerPairs = dealers.SelectMany( d => d.Cars.Select(car => new {Car = car, Dealer = d}));
   var groupsOfCars = carDealerPairs.GroupBy(pair => new {Make = pair.Car.Make, Model = pair.Car.Model});
   var groupsWithDuplicates = groupsOfCars.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);
   foreach (var grp in groupsWithDuplicates)
   {
       var car = grp.Key;
       var companies = grp.Select(c => c.Dealer);
       //do whatever
   }
   ```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VxT9Tm)

Comment: Problem is nicely broken and well articulated

Comment: Thank you very much. I was so fixed on my Data-structure that I didn't thought about creating a new "master list" with only one car-class per company. :-D